# Is FILTER_VALIDATE_URL being too strict?

Tags: php, url

In PHP, `filter_var('www.example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` returns `false`. Is this correct? Isn't `www.example.com` a valid URL, or protocols (http://, ftp://, etc.) need to be explicitly stated in the URL to be formally correct?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not a valid URL. Prefixing things with `http://` was never a very user-friendly thing, so modern browsers assume you mean http if you just enter a domain name. Software libraries are, rightly, a little bit more picky!

One approach you could take is passing the string through [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url), and then adding any elements which are missing, e.g.

```
if ( $parts = parse_url($url) ) {
   if ( !isset($parts["scheme"]) )
   {
       $url = "http://$url";
   }
}
```

Interestingly, when you use FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, it actually uses parse_url internally to figure out what the scheme is [(view source)](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#php_filter_validate_url). Thanks to salathe for spotting this in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll use the `parse_url` approach you said, I like it better than `filter_var`

Comment: Wednesday Trivia: `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` uses `parse_url()` to check to see if there is a scheme.

Comment: Nice! I'll add it to the answer!

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but what if the address should be https:// and not http://?

Also thanks for the help above!!

Comment: you could simply check if `$parts["scheme"]=='http'` and reconstruct the url as an https one?

Answer (score 3):

The URL have to correspond with the rules set forward in [RFC 2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html), and according to that spec the protocol is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Paul Dixon's answer I want to say that you can use [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) for `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` to specify which part of the URL must be presented.

```
FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED
FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED
FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED
FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED
```

Since PHP 5.2.1 `FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED` and `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` flags used by default and, unfortunately, there is no way to disable them (you **can't** do something like `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, ~FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED);` if the existence of the URL scheme part does not necessarily). It seems like a bug for me. There is a relative [bugreport](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72301).

Comment: This just seems to make it not validate any urls. https://3v4l.org/1TjA5

Comment: @RussellSilva, Derokorian You are right, I can not make it work. It looks like a bug for me. I updated my answer.

Comment: Some of these flags are not just deprecated but removed from the language as of PHP 8

Answer (score 1):

The scheme ("protocol") part is required for `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.