# Validating URL(s) with PHP Filtering

Tags: php, validation, url, filter

**FILTER_VALIDATE_URL** returns *true* when validating something like: `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com,` but returns *false* for `www.example.com`

Is there any flag that would allow urls like `www.example.com` to be validated as valid? I tried looking in the documentation but there was nothing that could potentially address the problem.

If there is no such flag, what should I use as an alternative method for validating url(s)?

Comment: You can look at my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596376/only-match-url-beginning-with-www-or-https I was looking for regex what will match these URLs (see an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the string through parse_url, and then adding any elements which are missing, e.g.

```
if ( $parts = parse_url($url) ) {
   if ( !isset($parts["scheme"]) )
   {
      $url = "http://$url";
   }
}
```

Then you should use $url with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL.

Have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800452/is-filter-validate-url-being-too-strict)

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)